# Android 4.0.4 tablet WiFi fails to connect due to bad authentication

Tags: wi-fi

I was already using the android 4.0.4 tablet with WiFi at my home. Very frustrated that when I just turned it on again today it was not able to connect.

Actually, it *does* connect - There appears to be two phases:

1. Connecting to WiFi
2. Authenticating
   a.  "Authenticating.."
   b. "Saved secured with WPA/WPA2"
   c.  "Authenticating"
   d.  "Authentication problem"

The first step is successful. The second fails at the step d.

Now, I had saved the password for the WPA/WPA2 network. So this is NOT a wrong password issue. But even so I did a "forget" and re-entered the password (with "show password" turned on to be sure).

What really bugs me here is there is no further information on "why" the authentication failed.

There are several other laptops in the home. They have not changed any settings for months (all DHCP with long leases).

Comment: Are you sure it is WPA and not WPA2 or another security protocol? The fact that it is failing to authenticate could mean it is using the wrong method. Also, your tablet should keep WiFi connection logs or you could download an app that logs them for you.

Comment: @enigma Thx for responding.  The message is "authenticating with wpa/wpa2".  Where would I look for the logs? I will try find / -name *.log

Comment: @enigma thanks again, will take bit of time to get that going. started the log daemon, but then figure out how where it is putting the logs. will get back.